Custom simple Storybook alternative using Vite
I am trying to create my simple Storybook-like alternative package called playground which is installed as dependency into other packages like foo-products or bar-products.
When I run playground play command from inside foo-products package I want to create running Vite app in dev mode which uses components located in playground package to build a site to play with components located in foo-products package.
This means I have to somehow launch a Vite app in such a way so it can use components both from playground and foo-products packages. More specifically I think I need to somehow "send" components from foo-products to Vite app in playground.
Let's say I have the following monorepo structure:
monorepo
- playground
  - cli.js
  - index.html
  - index.ts
  - SiteBuilderModule.ts

- foo-products
  - .play
    - play.config.ts
  - FooModule.ts

In play.config.ts I want to tell, which functions or components will be used on playground site:
// foo-products: play.config.ts

import { fooFunc } from 'FooModule';

export default {
    functions: [fooFunc, /* ... */]
}

Now I need to somehow receive these functions in index.ts file in playground package:
// playground: index.ts

import { functions } from '...???...'; // Receive `functions` from `foo-products:play.config.ts`

functions.each(func => console.log(func)); // fooFunc, ...

Finally, I need a cli.js to create Vite app when running playground play command inside foo-products package. I just copied code from Vite docs since I really don't know what to do here...
// playground: cli.js

#!/usr/bin/env node

import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url'
import { createServer } from 'vite'

console.log('Starting Playground Vite App!');

const __dirname = fileURLToPath(new URL('.', import.meta.url))

const server = await createServer({
  // any valid user config options, plus `mode` and `configFile`
  configFile: false,
  root: __dirname,
  server: {
    port: 1337,
  },
})
await server.listen()

server.printUrls()
server.bindCLIShortcuts({ print: true })

How do I configure cli.js so it can detect play.config.ts file in foo-products package, take functions from it and pass it to index.ts to create multi-package Vite app?

Took me almost 2 days to dig into VitePress and Storybook but finally I solved it!
I'm convinced again that Vite's Virtual Modules feature is an absolute miracle!
First of all, we setup paths to playground and test-products packages in CLI js file:
// playground: cli.ts NOTE .ts NOT .js!

const playgroundRoot = path.resolve(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url), '../..');
const productsRoot = process.cwd();

Then we need to create a virtual module to access .play/config.ts from our Vite app:
// playground: plugin.ts

import { type Plugin } from "vite";

export function playConfig(configPath: string): Plugin {
    const moduleId = 'virtual:play-config';

    return {
        name: moduleId,
        resolveId(id) {
            if (id === moduleId)
                return moduleId;
        },
        load(id) {
            if (id === moduleId)
                // Here we just tell Vite where to find config file.
                // It loads and parses it itself which is super cool
                return `
                    const playConfig = await import('${configPath}');
                    export default playConfig.default;
                `;
        }
    }
}

Now we go back to CLI file, register our virtual module plugin and pass it the path to .play/config.ts file located in test-products package:
// playground: cli.ts

const playgroundRoot = path.resolve(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url), '../..');
const productsRoot = process.cwd();

const viteServer = await createServer({
    configFile: false,
    root: path.resolve(playgroundRoot, 'app'),
    server: {
        port: 7000
    },
    plugins: [
        playConfig(normalizePath(productsRoot + '/.play/config.ts'))
    ]
});

await viteServer.listen();

viteServer.printUrls();
viteServer.bindCLIShortcuts({ print: true });

That is all!
Vite will automatically load everything at .play/config.ts and we can access this data inside our Vite app:
// app.ts

import playConfig from 'virtual:play-config';

console.log(playConfig);

Also, more advanced examples of working with Vite as a "generator tool" can be found at Vitepress and Storybook repositories.
Look for bin and cli scripts there.
For example, I did not know that Vite has a loadConfigFromFile function that can load any configuration files in any extension (.js, .ts, ...) out of the box!
